# Can't Upgrade to Python 3.12 on Windows 8.1 - No "Upgrade Now" Option

Tags: python

I am running Python 3.7.4 currently and need to upgrade to 3.12 on my Windows 8.1 PC.

When I run the installer I don't get an "Upgrade Now" option as the various guides I have read suggest:

[image]

I just get an "Install Now" option, like a fresh installation. Running that causes 3.12 to be installed alongside 3.7.

How do I upgrade to 3.12 so that 3.7 is also deleted?

Comment: Remove the old Python 3.7 first, then install the new 3.12. Upgrade now is only available within the same version tree.

Comment: That "Upgrade Now" is most likely only for "patch" versions (Versioning like: MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH) you can actually have multiple Python versions installed simultaneously in Windows.